# Calculations of induced charges after groundings by using Green's reciprocity

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

[image]

The 2 conductors exists as shown in the above diagram.

The inner conductor(We will call it as conductor1) has been surrounded by the outer conductor(We will call it as conductor2).

At the inital state, the conductor1 has the potential of $V_{1}$and the outer conductor has the potential of $V_{2}$

And it has been known that the point P shown  in the diagram has the potential of $V'$

Nextly we assume that the point P has been given the (point?) charge $q$ and the each conductor has been grounded.

What we want to do is to calculate the each induced charges (I interpreted as the total charge after the operations of giving $q$ and groundings)of the conductors using Green's reciprocity.

At the initial state, the below 6 formulas are held.

$$  V_{1}^{\left( 1 \right) } =V_{1}$$

$$  V_{2}^{\left( 1 \right) } =V_{2}$$

$$  V_{3}^{\left( 1 \right) } =V'$$

$$ ~  $$

$$\begin{aligned} Q_{1}^{\left( 1 \right)} &= Q_{1}:=\text{charge of conductor1}  \\\\ Q_{2}^{\left( 1 \right)} &= Q_{2}:=\text{charge of conductor2} \\\\ Q_{3}^{\left( 1 \right)} &= 0~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{point P hasn't any charge.}\end{aligned}$$

And at the 2nd state, the below 6 formulas are held.

$$\begin{aligned} V_{1}^{\left( 2 \right)}  &= 0 \\\\ V_{2}^{\left( 2 \right)}  &= 0 \\\\ V_{3}^{\left( 2 \right)}  &= V'':=\text{potential at point P}  \end{aligned}$$

$$ ~ $$

$$\begin{aligned} Q_{1}^{\left( 2 \right)}  &=q_{1} :=\text{charge of conductor1}  \\\\ Q_{2}^{\left( 2 \right)}  &=  q_{2}:=\text{charge of conductor2}\\\\  Q_{3}^{\left( 2 \right)} &= q \end{aligned}$$

$$ ~ $$

$$  \sum_{ k }^{  } V_{k}^{\left( 1 \right)} Q_{k}^{\left( 2 \right)} = \sum_{ k }^{  } V_{k}^{\left( 2 \right)} Q_{k}^{\left( 1 \right)}  $$

$$ ~ $$

$$  V_{1}^{\left( 1 \right)} Q_{1}^{\left( 2 \right)} + V_{2}^{\left( 1 \right)} Q_{2}^{\left( 2 \right)} + V_{3}^{\left( 1 \right)} Q_{3}^{\left( 2 \right)}  =V_{1}^{\left( 2 \right)} Q_{1}^{\left( 1 \right)} + V_{2}^{\left( 2 \right)} Q_{2}^{\left( 1 \right)} + V_{3}^{\left( 2 \right)} Q_{3}^{\left( 1 \right)} $$

$$ ~ $$

$$  V_{1} q_{1}+V_{2}q_{2}+V'q=0 \cdot Q_{1} + 0 \cdot Q_{2} + V'' \cdot 0 $$

$$ = 0 $$

The current problem for me begins from the below statement and the equation.

As $q$ is placed at the point P , the portion of electric lines of force of $q$ end to conductor1 and the other end in conductor2, hence ,

$$ q_{1}+q_{2}+q=0 $$

is held.

Why the above equation can be held?

I can obivously get that any electric line of force can't penetrate conductor since from the defintion of electric field(electric lines of force which penetrate unit area).

Answer (score 0):

$$q_{1}+q_{2}+q=0$$

The above equation must be held to make the potential at the outer conductor by zero.

$$\text{sum of electric field(s)}=\frac{\text{total charge}}{4 \pi r^{2} \epsilon_{0}}$$

The total charge is of course given by

$$q_{1}+q_{2}+q=0$$